# How to add View in react native during runtime?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm really confused on how to add (and delete) View and other such components during runtime,
for example in vanilla JavaScript you can use `document.querySelector('query-here').appendChild(element);`

but how do I achieve the same thing using react native? for example:

```
<Pressable onPress={()=>{addElement(element)}}>
<View>
 //add elements here
</View>
```

I know how to achieve it directly like this:

```
<View>
 {
  [...Array(23)].map((el, index) => {
    return(
     <View key={index}>
        <Text>added new element</Text>
     </View>
   )});
 }
</View>
```

could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can add and delete React-Native elements using state, and cannot delete by id or query because of the render cycle.

Comment: @ZuhairNaqi could you give me a sample code link or something? because I know how to use states for basic text but not for adding react native elements

Answer (score 2):

@cakelover here how you can add item and remove items based on component's state.

```
import { Button } from 'react-native';


const [loader, setLoader] = React.useState(false); //donot show loader at initial
    const showLoader = isShowLoader => { // based on this function you can add or remove single loader from UI
       setLoader(isShowLoader);
    }
    return (
       <View>
         {loader && <LoaderComponent/>}
         <Button
           onPress={() => setLoader(!loader)}
           title="Toggle Loader Component"
           color="#841584"
         />
       </View>
     )
```

If you want to add or remove multiple same components like list you should use arrays of items for that.

Comment: I'm starting to get an idea of what you mean
but could u add a button and make it add a view onPress so I can solidify my understanding?

Comment: Updated the example for you, bind the loader state to toggle loader on button press

Comment: as far as I can tell you arn't adding components,  you're toggling them on and off

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe you could try something like this

```
  export default function App() {

  const [num, setNum] = useState(() => 0);
  const [renderTasks, setRenderTasks] = useState(()=>taskcreate(0));


  function taskcreate()
  {
    let i=num;
    setNum(i+1);
    return(
      <View>
      {
        [...Array(i)].map((el, index) => {

          return (
            <View key={index}>
              <Text>hello there</Text>
            </View>
          )
        })
      }
      </View>
    )

  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Pressable style={{ height: 50, width: 50, backgroundColor: 'orange' }} onPress={() => { setRenderTasks(taskcreate()) }}></Pressable>
      { renderTasks }
    </View>
  );
}
```